# Existence of solutions of quadratic equations with multiple variables

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, roots, quadratic-forms

In an attempt to solve for stable solutions of certain non-autonomous differential equations, I arrived at the following quadratic equations
$$ 0= A_n x_n^2 + B_n x_n + C_n + \sum_{m=1 | m\neq n}^N D_{n,m} x_m $$
for the variables $x_n$ and real constants $A_n, B_n, C_n, D_{nm}$ for $n,m = 
 1,...,N  $
Can we say under which conditions on the constants, there are real solutions $(x_1,...,x_N)^T$?

For $N=1$ this becomes the standard quadratic equation
$$A_1 x_1^2 + B_1 x_1 +C_1 = 0 $$
with known solution formula. The existence of solutions boils down to checking the sign of the discriminant. Solutions disappear where the determinant equals zero. Is there any such criterion for $N=2$ or larger $N$?